# sql query order by multiple CAST value int

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to run this in sql query, but not working. I tried single cast, it works fine, but when i tried to add two cast, it gives error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM useradvert WHERE optionsalerent='For sale' ORDER BY cast (`rm` as signed)' at line 1

This query below works.

```
SELECT * FROM popol WHERE optsale='For sale' ORDER BY cast(rm as signed) ASC
```

THis one doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM popol WHERE optsale='For sale' ORDER BY cast(rm as signed) ASC, cast(salary as signed) ASC
```

I need to output both rm and salary rm. Both are integer values. Tqs in advance.

Comment: Is it really `select *`?

Comment: yes...all are slected and will be displayed tqs @juergen d

Comment: That is strange. Normally the error message starts right at the problematic point. So the `FROM` in the query and what is right before it

Comment: SELECT * FROM popol WHERE optsale='For sale' ORDER BY rm, salaryrm ASC....this works, but without the cast signed, it wont return values properly. How do i use two CAST SIGNED?

Comment: Both queries execute OK on my end. Are you sure `salary` is of `int` type?

Comment: i got this error it gives error #1064..if i use 2 cast signed

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the CASTs. And the error does not output that part of the query as problematic. Any hidden characters in your query? Type the first part again without copy/pasting it.

Comment: oo.. u mean i must set column salary as int in database? How come rm worked? because rm is not set as int. it's actually varchar but works fine if i use single CAST signed

Comment: oo sory all.. it works fine now. juergend d. u were right. i pasted something else..LoL

Comment: Put ur answers in the answer zone juergen. I will tick it as accept. tq